# Picasso ImageLoading issue(Parse.com)

Tags: android, parse-platform, imageview, picasso

I currently am trying to loading images in a listview,but the problem is that the images aren't loaded from the cache,the only time it works is if I use .fit(),but I have certain images that are 1280 x 720 and some are 500 x 500. I want them to scale to their own image size.

This is what I'm using right now.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(postList.get(position).postPicture).fit().into(holder.imageView);


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/postImage"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/postUsername"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with android:scaleType in your xml.

If you want to resize your image use this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(postList.get(position).postPicture).transform(new YourResizeTransformation(getContext()))
```

and your YourResizeTransformation class:

```
public class ResizeTransformation implements Transformation {
private Context context;

public ResizeTransformation(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
@Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
        if (result != source) {
            // Same bitmap is returned if sizes are the same
            source.recycle();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```